# Using Retrofit to get list of mail from RESTAPI from outlook?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

How I can use this GET (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages)
with Retrofit

I am trying with this but doesnt work

```
 @GET("/v1.0/me/messages")
    Call<ResponseBody> getMail(
            @Header("Content-type") String contentTypeHeader);
```

---

```
  public Call<ResponseBody> getDrive() {
        return mMSGraphAPIService.getMail("application/json");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Do you receive special 401 status code (from the documentation i can see you have to deal with the Authorization header) ?

Did you try the sample app ?

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/android-java-snippets-rest-sample/blob/316b389b6baa8f25d6d79ee5e2e6b150e54410ac/microsoftgraphapi/src/main/java/com/microsoft/office365/msgraphapiservices/MSGraphMailService.java